# Azure ChainedTokenCredential Fails after Password Change

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-identity

Azure `ChainedTokenCredential` fails for local development after password change. I've been using `ChainedTokenCredential` for several weeks to authenticate using `ManagedIdentityCredential` in Azure and `DefaultAzureCredential` for local testing of my Function App. Everything was working as exected. Here is a code example that was working and still works in Azure but not locally.

```
def get_client():

    MSI_credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    credential_chain = ChainedTokenCredential(MSI_credential, default_credential)

    storageurl = os.environ["STORAGE_ACCOUNT"]

    client = BlobServiceClient(storageurl, credential=credential_chain)
    return client
```

Last week I had to change my password and since then I get the following error.

```
[2021-04-19T15:18:06.931Z] SharedTokenCacheCredential.get_token failed: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-02-08T20:05:01.4240000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-04-15T15:49:33.0000000Z'.
[2021-04-19T15:18:06.963Z] Trace ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:06.972Z] Correlation ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:06.974Z] Timestamp: 2021-04-19 15:17:46Z'
[2021-04-19T15:18:06.977Z] DefaultAzureCredential.get_token failed: SharedTokenCacheCredential raised unexpected error "Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-02-08T20:05:01.4240000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-04-15T15:49:33.0000000Z'.
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.014Z] Trace ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.040Z] Correlation ID: 
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.046Z] Timestamp: 2021-04-19 15:17:46Z'"
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.061Z] DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
        ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
        SharedTokenCacheCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-02-08T20:05:01.4240000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-04-15T15:49:33.0000000Z'.
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.094Z] Trace ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.097Z] Correlation xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.108Z] Timestamp: 2021-04-19 15:17:46Z'
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.111Z] ChainedTokenCredential.get_token failed: DefaultAzureCredential raised unexpected error "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
        ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
        SharedTokenCacheCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-02-08T20:05:01.4240000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-04-15T15:49:33.0000000Z'.
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.147Z] Trace ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.181Z] Correlation ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.195Z] Timestamp: 2021-04-19 15:17:46Z'"
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.201Z] ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
        ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
        DefaultAzureCredential: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
        ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
        SharedTokenCacheCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-02-08T20:05:01.4240000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-04-15T15:49:33.0000000Z'.
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.241Z] Trace ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.264Z] Correlation ID: xxx
[2021-04-19T15:18:07.303Z] Timestamp: 2021-04-19 15:17:46Z'
```

Things I've tried to resolve the issue:

1. Signing in and out of VSCode Azure Extension
2. Signing in and out of `az cli`
3. `az account clear`
4. Clearing browser cache.
5. Restarting PC and VSCode.
6. Clearing VSCode Cache

   - `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache`
   - `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\CacheData`

I am using the Azure Extension 'Attach to Python Functions' to run the debugger. I am uncertain of how `DefaultAzureCredential` is obtaining my credentials. I believe it is stored locally because I get the same error when running the debugger while not signed into the Azure extension. I thought `DefaultAzureCredential` would use my Azure Extension sign in as me to authenticate but I am uncertain.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It appears you have a cached refresh token issued before the password change which `SharedTokenCacheCredential` is attempting to use. It should remove the token when it gets an error like the one you're seeing. Which version of azure-identity do you have installed? As a workaround, you can delete the cache the credential uses: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService\msal.cache` (doing so will log you out of Visual Studio).

Comment: Another workaround is to disable `SharedTokenCacheCredential`: `DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)`. Also, `DefaultAzureCredential` is [a chain of credentials which includes managed identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity#defaultazurecredential). Unless you need `ManagedIdentityCredential` before `EnvironmentCredential`, you could simply use `DefaultAzureCredential`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was resolve by using @Charles Lowell's solution. I was having trouble finding the file due to using fzf.exe (fuzzy finding tool) and it does not look in hidden folders by default. Removing `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\msal.cache` worked.

An alternative I found was using `VisualStudioCodeCredential()` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential()`. This uses the vscode extension to authenticate. I prefer this method but not all developers use VSCode. I'm glad to get `DefaultAzureCredential` working.

```
def get_client():

    MSI_credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
    vscode_credential = VisualStudioCodeCredential()
    credential_chain = ChainedTokenCredential(MSI_credential, vscode_credential)
```

More information on `DefaultAzureCredential()` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).

Thanks to all!

Comment: Just wanna say that deleting the C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\msal.cache file also worked to fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

After `az account clear`, you need to `az login` using your latest password, the one you can login azure portal.

[DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python) is based on [Azure Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python) client library. You could skip the shared cache with

```
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)
```

and try to authenticate via the Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by logging in through Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Tools > Options... > Azure Service Authentication

After logging in through VS, the authentication also worked again in Rider as well as the CLI.