# Azure CLI authentication ERROR: AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-maps

When trying to obtain a token from Azure Maps through a App Service, it return the following error.

```
"Azure CLI authentication failed due to an unknown error. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot ERROR: AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2022-12-13T05:31:55.3867300Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2023-01-28T06:51:55.0000000Z'.
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to clear the Local Azure Credentials and re-login.

```
az account clear
az login
```

Answer (score 1):

For the same error message, 
if the commands `az account clear` & `az login` does not work,

Please delete this folder in your local environment (windows only) `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService\msal.cache`according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165101/azure-chainedtokencredential-fails-after-password-change).